# ChromeOptions to save cookies/slow test execution

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, cookies, selenium-webdriver

At the moment I'm trying to create a ChromeOptions object to save cookies between page loads. Right now if I navigate to one page using `Navigate().GotUrl()` and then use the same command to go to another page the cookies don't save.

I have a work around where you save the cookies using a foreach loop

```
var cookies = chrome.Manage ().Cookies.AllCookies;
foreach(OpenQA.Selenium.Cookie cookie in cookies)
{
    chrome.Manage().Cookies.AddCookie(cookie);
}
```

But I'd like to avoid having to add that in my tests, this is what I have for the ChromeOptions object so far

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
[SetUp ()]
        public void SetUp ()
        {
            options.AddArguments ("user-data=C:/Users/temp/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data");
            options.AddArguments ("--start-maximized");
        }
```

Is there an argument I can add to keep the cookies saved always?

**EDIT** - Apparently issue isn't with the cookies, but it seems to be the speed of the execution of tests, is there anyway to slow the execution speed using ChromeOptions?

Comment: Execution speed is in Selenium.  You can set the general speed, but frankly I would add waits for specific elements in your tests.  The speed causing problems is part of the UI experience and it would be good to know exactly what is causing the problems to properly test the application.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following and see if that solves the issue.

```
options.AddArgument("--allow-file-access-from-files");
options.AddArgument("--enable-file-cookies");
```

If you are still having problems remove the web security.  It will throw an error but hopefully allow it to function correctly.

```
options.AddArgument("--disable-web-security");
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion, still running into the same issue if I remove my work around

Comment: Added another one...Mine works without cookie issues, but I'm not sure if it's your site specifically or one of these...